# How to detect window width with jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm using responsive design, therefore I need to get the width of the window.

This is a jquery solution for it.

```
 $(document).ready(function{
   var width = $(window).width();
   $(window).resize(function(){
     width = $(window).width();
   })

   if(width <= 480){
     //do something
  }

 })
```

Now, I'm having the follow question:

Can I call 'detectWidth' in each template like I did here?

```
  if(detectWidth <= 480){
      //do something
  }
```

And will 'detectWidth' return the correct size even when I resize the screen?

Regards

Comment: What's the question here?  Does `$(window).width()` not work?

Comment: You can just call `$(window).width();` when you want the width.

Comment: i want a function to call anywhere when i want get width of screen !!
ex : function DetectWidth( //=== return width of screen !!)

Comment: You can call `$(window).width()` from anywhere when you want to get the width of the screen. Your `DetectWidth` function would be redundant.

Comment: Apparent misunderstanding of jQuery function scope.

Comment: yes , i know , so i need it when window resize too !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to get the width of the current window:

```
$(window).width()
```

And yes, it will give the updated amount even when the user changed the size of the window.

Comment: example my function to get detectWidth !

      function detectWidth(){
           var width = $(window).width();
           $(window).resize(function(){
              width = $(window).width();
           })
           return width;
      }

I do not think it worked well, but I have no other solution !!